# Arcgis js Mobile with dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis

i developing a demo with ARCGIS Javascript and DOJO for mobile devices but i have a trouble, im using this example (http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/mobile_drawtoolbar/ , https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/mobile_drawtoolbar.html) to test in various devices (samsung, sony xperia, iphone, ipad) and works in ipad, iphone (I tried it in the browser chrome with the option "Toggle device mode") but dont work in other mobile devices.

ANYONE could help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial states that this application is intended only for iOS devices:

> "This sample shows how to use the draw and edit toolbars when building an application designed to run on an iOS device."

Still, I looked through the code and also tested this on Android on a Samsung Galaxy S5 and it works fine. What specific errors are you seeing? The error messages in the browser console would help us identify the issue.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering the question. the console does not show me any error. Select device Samsung Galaxy 4 and the option "Polyline", the message "tap to start draw, double tap to complete", but when I do the sinnlge tap on the screen does not draw, if I double tap on the screen draws the first element polyline and if I make a simple tap does not draw anything until I double tap but ends.
There any example to run on any mobile device?